# Using base class methods to initialize derived class members

Tags: c++

Is it legal? If so, do you consider it as good coding practice?

I want to do something like this (nonessential details are not shown):

```
class ItemStorage {
    int size() const;
};

class SpecialStorage : public ItemStorage  {
public:
    SpecialStorage (...) : ItemStorage(...), items(ItemStorage::size()) {...}
private:
    int items;
};
```

I am pretty sure that it is OK if the method **size** is not virtual. What if it is virtual and the derived class doesn't overwrite it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general rule is that, during initialization, you must not access uninitialized parts of the object. As ItemStorage is already initialized when items gets initialized, calling size is indeed fine.

Even if size was virtual, and even if it was overwritten, it still would be fine: it would just call the base version (i.e. virtual methods only bind to the level which is under construction).

Comment: +1: I didn't notice that ItemStorage's constructor gets called first.

Comment: It would call the base version only because it is explicitly specified. Otherwise the object under construction is SpecialStorage, and in this case the call might not be safe (relying on yet uninitialized members).